# Publishing a website on the internet

Tags: php, html, wampserver

I finished my two first websites (one static and the other is dynamic) ,now I have to publish them on the internet,I dont know the process, should I have a domain for both of them?

I will add the static website as a link in existant website, i have been told that a static website don't need a domain!
I have serached into the internet to learn how to publish them:

```
http://www.wikihow.com/Publish-a-Web-Site-on-Your-Own-Domain
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8DlIvat7m4&list=PL0B2E90AFC0367264&index=1
```

I have used :wampserver,html,php

Comment: so what problem u r facing? where u need help in domain or in hosting or in any where else?

Comment: Have you bought a domain ?

Comment: Have a look at this. [website-hosting-process](http://www.thehostingwebsite.com/website-hosting-process)

Answer (score 3):

You need:

- **A domain name** e.g. example.com, [NameCheap](http://namecheap.com) ain't too shabby
- **PHP Hosting** - somewhere for your site to live, and where your domain name will point to
- **FTP software**, to upload all your files to the server you purchase, theres a multitude of free software out there for this - [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is an excellent choice

Have a look around for each of these, to start with you'll probably want **shared hosting** - the most affordable and usually easiest to set up. And if you have problems with an specific area, then have a Google, because someone will likely have already experienced the same.

Check out [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/webhost/) for a great guide on hosts and loads more info.

Comment: FTP software should maybe be listed as optional - since a lot of hosting companies allow you to upload your site in different ways, e.g. in a web ui where you upload a .zip